# Reload page causes routing error after editing validation errors

Tags: routes, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a typical maintenance, as scaffold does, but the edit and update routes are not generated with `resources`:

```
get "users/edit", as: "edit_user"
patch "users/update"
```

When the `update` action fails I `render :edit` showing the errors, and then, if I reload the page the browser sends a GET with the url of the update (POST) and this creates a routing error... try to explain for example :

1) GET:http://localhost:3001/ca/users/edit

2) User edits and causes a validation error and submit

3) POST: http://localhost:3001/ca/users/update => error => render :edit

4) the browser shows the edit form and in the URL direction there is "...users/update" (not "...users/edit")

5) the user reload the page (F5 unintentionally) => routing ERROR

This causes routing ERROR because the browser sends GET with a url that corresponds to POST ("..users/update")

I know that with `resources :users` this issue does not exist, does not crash, the browser sends a POST (after F5), my problem is that with my own routes the browsers sends a GET

How does Rails do, to send a PATCH or POST when user reload the page after `render :edit` with errors?